# Wrong total price in Python calculation program that sums the cost of parcels with different weights

Tags: python, calculation

Working on a python program that asks a user for the amount of parcels to send and the weight of the parcels, the program then multiplies a fixed cost to each parcel depending on the weight given a number of intervals. Problem I face is that whenever I execute my code I get the wrong total cost when I type in the values as seen in the image. It should sum up to $1109 but I get $1262 instead.

[image description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hBOCj.png)

My code:

```py
max_2 = 30 
between_2_6 = 28 
between_6_12 = 25 
over_12 = 23 
i=0                                                                  #Variable for calcuclation
total_price=0                                                            #Start value of total price


parcel=float(input("How many parcels do you want to send?  "))



while i<parcel:                                                         #While loop which applies for i<input value from value
  i+=1                                                                  #Add 1 to i för att reduce repetitions
  weight = float(input("How much does your parcel weigh " +str(i)+ "?: "))             #weight with decimals
  if weight <= 2:                                     
    price=weight*max_2 
  elif (weight > 2 or weight <= 6): 
    price=weight*between_2_6 
  elif (weight > 6 or weight <= 12): 
    price=weight*between_6_12 
  elif weight > 12: 
    price=weight*over_12                                                  
   
  total_price+=price                                                        #total_price=sum of all prices for respective parcel
 
print(str(total_price)+"USD")
```

Comment: please add your code as a ```code block``` in the question

Comment: why `parcel` is a float. looks like it should be `int`

Comment: the problem is in the first two elif conditions. I think you will learn more when you figure it out by yourself

Comment: btw, there are `for loops` which are meant for looping when you know the number of loops

Comment: also it says in the table that _up to 2_ would cost 30 dollars, but _from 2 up to 6_ would also include the 2, no? I would say that `up to` is not inclusive meaning that the 2 packages would cost 28 dollars and only if you pick one package would it cost 30 dollars

Answer (score 0):

Below is the correct working program. It gives the output you expected. The only changes i made are in the `elif` conditions. First i have used `and` instead of `or`. Secondly note the parenthesis(although not necessary in this case) around individual conditions.

```
max_2 = 30 
between_2_6 = 28 
between_6_12 = 25 
over_12 = 23 
i=0                                                                  #Variable for calcuclation
total_price=0                                                            #Start value of total price


parcel=float(input("How many parcels do you want to send?  "))



while i<parcel:                                                         #While loop which applies for i<input value from value
  i+=1                                                                  #Add 1 to i för att reduce repetitions
  weight = float(input("How much does your parcel weigh " +str(i)+ "?: "))             #weight with decimals
  if weight <= 2:                                     
    price=weight*max_2 
  elif ((weight > 2) and (weight <= 6)): #and is used instead of or. Also note the parenthesis around the individual conditions
    price=weight*between_2_6 
  elif ((weight > 6) and (weight <= 12)): #and is used instead of or. Also note the parenthesis around the individual conditions
    price=weight*between_6_12 
  elif weight > 12: 
    price=weight*over_12                                                  
   
  total_price+=price                                                        #total_price=sum of all prices for respective parcel
 
print(str(total_price)+"USD")
```

Note: The parenthesis around the individual conditions are not necessary in this case. But i like to keep them there. You can remove them if you want.

Comment: add explanation as to what you have changed and why, the answer can really be shortened to _"use `and` instead of `or`"_, also the expressions can be shortened to `elif 2 < weight <= 6:` instead of `elif weight > 2 and weight <= 6`, and use a `for loop` instead of `while`

Comment: btw you don't need to use parentheses here at all

Comment: Ofcourse there are many variations of the same program. That is there are many ways the same program can be written giving the same output. Mine is one such example.

Comment: no, I wasn't giving you a different approach, literally the same thing just shorter, like this: `elif 2 < weight <= 6` is literally the same as `elif weight > 2 and weight <= 6` and you don't need the parentheses anyways (in this case (sometimes they are necessary but not here))

Comment: You can add whatever syntactic sugar you want. `2< weight <=6` will essentially be expanded to what i wrote.